# Writing custom for loop in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, overloading

I wondered if that would be possible, a custom for loop. The one I had in mind was the foreach expression from java, which is

```
for(Container c : Element e){
      // do stuff with e
}
```

I wanted to write it for a custom container I wrote (lets call it cust_cont), which I wanted to work with a foreach loop (like the one from boost). But before reading into iterators and such, I wanted to ask wether I can just implement the loop I want, if need explicitly.

Comment: If you are using C++0x that is already a feature. Else i'd guess not, at least not using the for keyword, since that expects another syntax.

Comment: @RedX: I think the question is about using the syntax without implementing iterators for the custom container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but yes, you have to implement `begin()` and `end()` methods (ideally overloaded on `const`) in order for iteration to work on  your custom container. Also, you need nested `iterator` and `const_iterator` types (or typedefs). To summarize, here is what you need:

member types:

```
MyClass::iterator
MyClass::const_iterator
```

member functions:

```
MyClass::iterator MyClass::begin();
MyClass::const_iterator MyClass::begin() const;
MyClass::iterator MyClass::end();
MyClass::const_iterator MyClass::end() const;
```

Answer (score 3):

Such loop is called *range-based loop* which is a feature added in C++0x.

So in C++0x, you can write this:

```
for(Element e : c) {
      // do stuff with e
}
```

where `c` is a container of object of type `Element`, and  which has defined `begin` and `end`  as member functions, OR can be passed to `begin()` and `end()` functions which are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (ADL), and `std` is one of the associated namespace(s).

Comment: I never knew that worked.. I guess I should read the 0x documentation more thoroughly. Thanks

Comment: @Nawaz: is it `std::begin` and `std::end`, or is it a free function `begin` and `end` that can be found via typical ADL ? `swap` uses ADL, for example.

Comment: @Matthieu:  You are right. They're looked up with ADL. Edited the answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: I am still fuzzy on C++0x, I blame the lack of experience :D I note that Clang 3.0 seem to provide it though, nice :D

Answer (score 0):

you can write a macro, something like this:

```
foreach(Element, e, c) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [fredoverflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979628/3681671) on how to do this for a custom container but since c++11 this became even easier using auto

```
for(auto element : container)
    //do something with element
```